# orderby not working for query_posts using array of IDs

Tags: query-posts, attachments, array, order, id

I have an array of IDs that i send to query_posts to get the posts (which works fine) but it seems to always put the attachment(562) last even though it is the newest. Also tried title and ASC vs DESC but its always last?

```
$slide_args = array( 
    'post_type'   => 'attachment', 
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'fields'      => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'media_tag',
            'terms'    => 'new-work',
            'field'    => 'slug',
        )
    )
);

$slide_attachments = new WP_Query($slide_args);

$sticky_ids = get_option('sticky_posts');

$slideshow_posts = array_merge($slide_attachments->posts,$sticky_ids) ;

// creates Array ( [0] => 562 [1] => 479 [2] => 598 [3] => 686 ) 
// 562 is an attachment, the others are posts

$postsargs = array(             
    'orderby'       => 'date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',  
    'post_status'   => 'published',
    'post_type'     => array( 'attachment', 'post' ),
    'post__in'      => $slideshow_posts,
);

query_posts( $postsargs );
```

anyone know what might be going on? Best, Dc.

Comment: What happens if you change the second `post_status` arg to 'any'?

Comment: no change i'm afraid...

Comment: Darn. I'm surprised the attachment shows up at all, considering that attachments never have the published status.

Comment: really? Used this several times but never had to use the orderby var before...

Comment: See: the 'attachment' post_type description: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters

Comment: What return do you get from `print_r( $slide_attahments->posts )`?

Comment: for print_r( $slide_attachments->posts ) & print_r( $sticky_ids ); i get Array ( [0] => 562 ) & Array ( [0] => 479 [1] => 598 [2] => 686 ). And then the merge obviously gives me Array ( [0] => 562 [1] => 479 [2] => 598 [3] => 686 ).

Comment: @mrwweb - i've tried ally he settings for post_status and it still always appears last?

Comment: And what happens if you use `WP_Query()` for your final result, rather than `query_posts()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. You're querying for sticky posts. Attachments can't be sticky at least by default. Hence, you're see the normal loop order when sticky posts are involved. So if you add this to your second args array:

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
```

I think your problem should be resolved.

Here's the [relevant codex section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Sticky_Post_Parameters) on that argument.

Comment: this has fixed it! So it was forcing the sticky posts to the top of the list as they were sticky and the media item wasn't. Cheers mrwweb!